# prm0009.dll cannot be repaired sfc /scannow

Tags: windows-10, bsod

My Windows 10 Pro has recently started blue screening about once or twice a week. I would try some tweaks from google searches of the BSODs, at least 6 different ones, that people had said worked.

I did a "fresh" install, meaning I updated from 8.1 to 10 then ran Windows Reset. This was approximately 2 months ago after my SSD (which was found to be healthy) decided it didn't want to boot.

Today however it has crashed four times so far. So I ran the SFC /scannow utility and it found one un-repairable dll called "prm0009.dll". It resides within the `%windir%\WinSxS`folder. In particular, the folder is named

`C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordbreaker7-english_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_74c5ad926cf35d8d\prm0009.dll`

I have spent the past hour trying to google what it is for and where it came from and where I can get a replacement version. I searched my entire C:\ to see if another one existed but this is the only instance of the file.

Here is a link to the sfcdetails.txt file that I generated from the cbs.log file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/260111/sfcdetails.txt

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you consider backing up files? I would recommend a full disk wipe as to have seeing many issues with a 8.1 to Windows 10 upgrade. Also do you have the Windows product key? I would be happy to walk you though a wipe and reinstall. Also I don't even see this file on my pc.

Comment: Good news, the file sfc can't repair, isn't a Windows file and not required for Windows to function

Comment: 8.1 and 10 Both automatically detects the key, the key isn't required, to reinstall either!

Comment: @Ramhound that's what I was thinking but this is the only solid lead I've gotten so far with this issues.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow I'm not adverse to it (vast majority of my non-os data is on other drives) but I'd prefer to leave that as a last resort.

Comment: @Anders - It has nothing to do with your issue.  A Windows Store game is corrupted.  [Word Breaker 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/word-breaker/9nblggh081xb).  Any event my research points to it not being a critical file.

Comment: @Ramhound hmm I never installed this or any other windows store game for that matter. What is the best way to see if it got installed by something else? I am very careful about installing software and since I recently formatted I only have been installing apps and games as I wanted to use them.

Comment: @Anders Windows 10 automatically includes a bunch of one click links to install games and such from the Windows Store. You may have accidentally clicked one of these.

Comment: You can mount an ISO, point DISM to the .wim on the mounted installation volume, in order to repair that file but again that isn't the source of your BSODs.  Why are you using SFC instead DISM anyways?

Comment: @Ramhound since it appears to be part of this game, is should safe to rename as it may be the culprit to my crashes since this is the only thing sfc found?

Comment: I misidentied the file, but its still not going to crash your system, because its corrupt.

Comment: I was also wrong, after bringing up my testing VM I discovered the file on the system. It is part of the Word Pad program, which while not critical is a system program. I have a clean copy and we can try to replace yours with mine. http://i.imgur.com/L18pdK9.png

Comment: @CharlesLudlow Great I will give it a try. I also analyzed my .dmp files and these were the apparent offending modules as called out by the WhoCrashed program:  ntoskrnl.exe, atikmpag.sys and fltmgr.sys. I did a full remove and clean install of my graphics driver with the most up-to-date official AMD driver. The atimpag.sys was only thrown once as far as I can tell. So far (finger's crossed) there hasn't been any crashes since earlier when I opened this thread.

Comment: @Anders here is the amd64 file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BytWKb9FB0iJNzVUZHNnQ1dRQ1E/view?usp=sharing I can also provide the one from an x86 install if necessary.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow got the file downloaded but I cannot replace it. Tried safe mode, taking ownership with my user name, gave full permissions to myself (and the built in admin account) etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try getting yourself into the F8 menu. http://i.imgur.com/GulXQAk.jpg Note that I am doing this from a VM and you may have to use Fn-F8 or possibly another combination.

Comment: I just got it to work. I made a batch file then booted to safe mode with command prompt. About to run sfc again to see if it still shows up corrupt.

Comment: Very good, let me know if it works.

Comment: No errors found this time around! At least this is a step forward! I will go back to doing the tasks I was doing most often when the BSODs would occur and see if system stability has improved. Thanks for the help thus far @CharlesLudlow!

Comment: No problem, if this solves the issue I'll make it into an answer that way if someone else has the same thing they don't have to sort through our comments for the solution.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow Almost a day later no crashes so far. I used my computer about 4 hours after replacing that corrupted dll and the subsequent SFC /scannow verifying integrity, and has been running since then. I host a PleX media server as well as playing video games, programming and general web browsing and media watching. Things are looking good so far! I will give a tertiary report tomorrow evening so you can create an answer if all is well. However, the mods closed this as a dupe so I am unsure if you'll be able to. Thanks again my friend!

Comment: @Anders No problem.

Comment: @magicandre1981 please reopen this question. While this does deal with the SFC utility it is Windows 10 not 8 and dealt with different files.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow **no**, Win8 and WIN10 work the same to fix corruptions. Use DISM and don't copy/paste files, this is so Vista/7 "fixing".before DISM was able to fix those corruptions.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried to DISM as Ramhound suggested but it did not work. The only thing that helped me was manually replacing the corrupted dll with the one CharlesLudlow provided. I did try the steps outlined in the possible dupe but all I got were errors.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow no crashes thus far. I'd say for whatever reason that dll was causing havoc. If we can get magicandre1981 to allow you to post an answer I'll give you the credit.